# Value not updating inside a ReactJS function

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a ReactJs function that displays a simple dialogue box, and is intended to update a value for the parent component.  The function looks like this:

```
export function MyDialogue(props: IMyProps) {    
    var myValue = 0;

    return (
        <div style={style}>
            <label>Enter a number here: </label>
            <input type="text" value={myValue} />
            <button onClick={() => props.updateFunc(myValue)}>Update</button>
        </div>
    );        
}
```

I've tried several variations of this; for example, passing in `props.myValue`, and even changing the function to a class and passing `this.state.myValue` in.  In all but this example, myValue remains as it was in the parent class, and in this version, always 0.

`updateFunc` simply calls `setState` on the parent class, and having traced through it, it never gets called with the changed value.

I've seen some documentation that says to essentially handle the onChange event - is this the only way to make this work, or is there a way to implement data binding in React?

Comment: Does the value in your textbox change, when you type, i don't think it will be changing right ?

Comment: Not when I use `var myValue = 0`.  It does change (visibly) when I use one of the other approaches, but the value never updates in the background

Comment: Can you update your code to the latest, so that I can get you a fix

Comment: That is the latest.  The other approaches don't work any better; it's just this one visibly prevents updating.

Comment: You didn' t do anything to change myValue in MyDialogue. This function just return 0 to your parent when you press the button. You need to use onChange event to pass the changes in your input.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change this component to a **stateful** component

then do a **two-way binding** for your **textbox** and have it talk to local **state** and then use that state value to update parent component.

```
export class MyDialogue extends React.Component<IMyProps, {}>{
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            myValue: 0
        }
    }

    onChangeHandler = (event:any) =>{
      this.setState({myValue:event.target.value});
    }

    return (
        <div style={style}>
            <label>Enter a number here: </label>
            <input type="text" value={this.state.myValue} onChange={this.onChangeHandler}/>
            <button onClick={() => props.updateFunc(this.state.myValue)}>Update</button>
        </div>
    );        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just bind back your input to the parent's state via `props.value`;

**MyDialogue.js**

```
export function MyDialogue(props: IMyProps) {    
  return (
      <div style={style}>
        ...
        <input type="text" value={props.value} />
        ...
      </div>
  );        
}
```

**Parent.js**

```
....
render(){
   const { dialogueValue } = this.state;

   return <MyDialuge value={dialogueValue} updateFunc={this.handleUpdate} />

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using uncontrolled input because You are not keeping value of input inside state.
Solution is

With **uncontrolled**:

```
export class MyDialogue extends React.Component<IMyProps, {}>{
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.input = React.createRef();
    }

    return (
        <div style={style}>
            <label>Enter a number here: </label>
            <input type="text" ref={this.input} />
            <button onClick={() => props.updateFunc(this.input.current.value)}>Update</button>
        </div>
    );        
}
```

With **controlled**:

1. Maintain myValue state in parent and pass it to child.
   and on change on input event call a function of parent which change myValue using **setState**,
2. Maintain myValye state inside MyDialogue and onClick pass it to parent.